# Анимация снизу вверх циклическая

Tags: android, android-animation

Как сделать анимацию, в которой задний фон будет уходить вверх и появляться снизу? Не так как в ответе, а чтобы картинка двигалась вверх и попиксельно вылезала снизу сразу. Тоесть вот ряд пикселей ушел наверх и сразу появился снизу

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален :)

Comment: Наверно, надо добавить снизу ImageView, устанавливать ему снимок лейаута и анимировать одновременно картинку и лейаут (первое что приходит в голову) . Правда на костыль похоже.

Comment: Открыл конкурс :)

Comment: Я делал такое в Юнити для андроида, не помню как только, сейчас поищу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите анимировать просто картинку, тогда всё просто. Внизу неё добавим `ImageView`, которому мы установим основную картинку.
Разметка:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="*вашакартинка*"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="*вашакартинка1*"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
<FrameLayout/>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView content = findViewById(R.id.content);
    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    img.setImageDrawable(content.getDrawable());

    final int s = Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF;        
    final TranslateAnimation animForContent = new TranslateAnimation(s, 0f, s, 0f, s, 0f, s, 1f);
    animForContent.setDuration(3000);
    final TranslateAnimation animForImg = new TranslateAnimation(0f, s, 0f, s, -1f, s, 0f);
    animForImg.setDuration(3000);
    animForImg.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            img.startAnimation(animForImg);
            content.startAnimation(animForContent);
        }
    });
    img.startAnimation(animForImg);
    content.startAnimation(animForContent);
}
```

Comment: Я еще не тестил, мне интересно, все волшебство в `setImageMatrix`? Зачем верхнему `ImageView` видимость `gone`?

Comment: Непонятно что происходит. Дергается

Comment: Да, я его сразу стер :) попробовал, все так же. Я задал `background` разного цвета двум `ImageView` для теста, это может быть причиной неработоспособности?

Comment: Я сделал это :)

Comment: @Flippy я исправил теперь должно работать

Answer (score 11):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        img1.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:background="#c8df0a0a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### translate.xml

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:duration="2000"
android:fromYDelta="100%"
android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Comment: @Sharwz Andrei, спасибо большое. но мне нужно немного не так. на заднем фоне остаётся белый экран. нужно сделать чтобы он так же динамично анимировал. и чтобы их общая анимация была плавной...

Comment: вы задали вопрос, я ответил. Сейчас даете детали, которые меняют суть анимации, в этом нет никакой сложности, просто добавьте строчку кода, с анимацией для заднего фона и у вас будет нужный вам эффект, фон будет вместе с вашей картинкой смещаться вместе и появляться. И будет очень плавно...

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `ViewFlipper`.

Разметка:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="1500" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="*вашакартинка*" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="*вашакартинка*" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    flippyFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    Animation animFlipIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flip_in);
    Animation animFlipOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flip_out);
    flippyFlipper.setInAnimation(animFlipIn);
    flippyFlipper.setOutAnimation(animFlipOut);
    flippyFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
    flippyFlipper.showNext();
}
```

flip_in:

```
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

flip_out:

```
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Comment: Ок, уговорили :)