# Android Animation

Tags: android, xml, анимация, android-animation

Необходимо реализовать следующую анимацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

RelativeLayout улетает направо на 100% и потом этот же Layout с анимацией появляется слева.

Comment: 2 разных анимации, которые следуют друг за другом. Сначала выводите за экран справа, и по окончанию - вводите слева.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508412/191270 то? Или нужно переделать слева - направо ? )))